# Дебаг java applet в эклипсе

Tags: отладка, applet, java

Проблема следующая, выполнил все действия, описанные в мануале [Debugging Java Applets in Eclipse](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/08/20/debugging-java-applets-in-eclipse). Но при запуске дебагера из эклипса появляется сообщение с невозможностью подключиться к VM.

Какие могут быть подводные камни? Windows 7 x64. Изменял настройки параметры среды, как из контрольной панели, так и напрямую в папке Java. Итог один и тот же...

Раньше делал, все работало. Не пойму в чем может быть дело.

Answer (score 2):

Для 64-х разрядной системы надо иметь оба комплекта JRE/JDK и 32-х разрядную и 64-х разрядные версии. 32-х разрядное приложение будет вызывать 32-х разрядную JVM, а 64-х разрядное будет вызывать 64-х разрядную JVM.

Comment: Это я понимаю, вношу изменения в параметры среды именно (x86), потому что именно ее использует Eclipse... Но ничего хорошего не выходит (

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед поставьте оба комплекта - вы же не знаете что там в кишках какие приложения что запускают. Скорее всего где-то требуется x64, а его у вас нет. Может ваш браузер его требует - ставьте JRE/JDK х64 потом если не работает будем дальше решать